# iOS Charts - Objective C, not Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, ios-charts

I'm using the chart library for iOS from here:
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

There's a good tutorial here:
https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

The issue is labeling. The chart allows you to label the x coordinates using the init method in Swift:
let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)

I don't see an equivalent in Objective C. There are plenty of Objective C examples on the GitHub site but they don't show you how to set x value labels. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent Objective-C code would be:

```
LineChartData * lineChartData = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithXVals:dataPoints
                                                            dataSets:lineChartDataSet];
```

Comment: I'm using the latest version I see (2.2.5) but I get an error trying to use this. No visible interface for LineChartData declares the selector initWithXVals:.